# Superimpose plots and more plots on the screen at the same time

Tags: python, plot, real-time

I want to superimpose two plots, one with data recorded prior and one with real data that are constantly updating (taken from a sensor). How can I do that? I tried like this but this is not working (the random data are just an example of the loop that will contain real time data extraction). Moreover, I would like on the screen 3 plots at a time (xy, yz, xz reference frames). Can anybody help me?

```
path = np.loadtxt("path.txt").reshape(-1, 3)
x = path[:,0]
y = path[:,1] 
z = path[:,2] 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#ax.scatter(x, y , s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='first')

plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 1])

for i in range(10):
    p = np.random.random()
    ax.scatter(x, y , s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='first')
    ax.scatter(i, p , s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='second')
    #plt.scatter(i, y)
    plt.pause(0.1)


plt.show()
```